# Why won't Xcode commit some artifacts as part of folder context commit?

Tags: ios, xcode, git

In Xcode, I created a new project and in the wizard opted to create a git repo.  When the wizard finished, all the artifacts were committed to git.

As I've been editing, whenever I right-click on the top/first yellow folder in the Project Navigator and choose 'Source Control > Commit Selected Files', some file types (.storyboard, main.m, .xcdatamodeld) cannot be committed from the commit window that displays.

The Project Manager displays the 'M' icon to the right of all these files, so it knows they are modified.  Furthermore, if I right-click on the individual file and do the commit, it allows me to commit.

I'm using Xcode v4.5.2.

Two questions:

1. Why does it list the '.storyboard' in the commit window, but will not let me select it for commit?
2. Why do the other files (main.m, .xcdatamodeld) not even display in the commit window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the "Source Control -> Commit..." from the "File" menu, or Option-Command-C and you will be able to commit the .storyboard along with the other files in your project.

The context menu "Commit Selected Files..." only seems to allow working with files that were explicitly selected before entering the commit window. Even though it shows the files that were modified, you cannot select them.

Comment: (Guess they moved it..."Source Control" is in the main menu in Xcode 5)